# COUNT(DISTINCT on end of month

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a db with logs of TSTAMP USERNAME SUBCR_TYPE and BALANCE.
I want to know how many users had at each past end of month a positive BALANCE by SUBSCR_TYPE

The resulting table should look like this

```
         silver|gold|platinum
2011-09      34|56  |109
2011-10      23|43  |67
2011-11      33|56  |45
.
.
.
```

I have tried this with obviously wrong results

```
SET @ts = unix_timestamp(LAST_DAY('2011-09-01'));
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USERNAME) AS 'silver'
FROM accLog_table 
WHERE BALANCE>=1 
AND SUBSCR_TYPE = 'silver'
AND TSTAMP<@ts
```

how can I do this correctly?

Comment: This is not answerable without details on the semantics of the table.  When is a record with a balance created?  My guess is you want to select the latest record for each user that is before the end of the month (which could be in the month or years earlier if there's been no activity recently) and then summarize those records by subscription type.  But that's only a guess, you'll have to clarify the question.

Comment: Your guess is correct. The record with a balance was created on activity. A user could indeed be last active 8 month ago and still have a positive balance, so he should count as 1 every month. I guess that's exactly my problem. The db only goes back 8 mont, if that makes things easier.

Comment: I have started to do the accounting at every end of the month, which  makes things easier. I just need the figures for the past missed months.

Comment: Can anybody in this community help me to sort this out? Do I need to rephrase the question, I just realized that I was voted down.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, the question is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happy to post a solution that worked for me

```
     SET @ts = unix_timestamp(LAST_DAY('2011-09-01'));       
     SET @subcr = 'silver';
            INSERT 
            INTO monthlyLiveAccess (
                timePeriod,
                silver
            )
            SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(@ts), "%Y-%m") AS timePeriod,
                COUNT(*) AS silver FROM (
                SELECT t.* from(
                    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(DATE_TIME), "%Y-%m %H:%i:%s") AS "timePeriod", 
                    USERNAME, BALANCE
                    from accLog_table
                    WHERE N_BALANCE>1
                    AND DATE_TIME<@ts
                    AND SUBSCR='silver'
                ORDER BY timePeriod desc) as t
                GROUP BY USERNAME) AS t1
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE silver = VALUES(silver);
```